# Does CoffeeScript have something like wildcard binding in destructing assignment?

Tags: coffeescript

In Scala, I can do things like:

```
val List(first, _, third) = List(1, 2, 3)
// first = 1
// third = 3
```

I currently have some CoffeeScript code in which I'm also not interested some elements in the array. Ideally, I would like to use a wildcard, like I'm doing in Scala.

```
[first, _, third] = [1, 2, 3]
```

Now, this does work, but it also adds this assignment:

```
_ = 2
```

… which is clearly not what I want. (I'm using underscore.) What's the preferred way of ignoring values in the array?

By the way, I'm using this for regular expression matching; the regular expression I'm using has optional groups that are really there for matching only, not to get any real data out.

```
match = /^(([a-z]+)|([0-9]+)) (week|day|year)(s)? (before|after) (.*)$/.exec str
if match?
  [__, __, text, number, period, __, relation, timestamp] = match
  …
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/aseemk/8637896 -- upcoming changes in 1.7 that may be relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific case you could bypass the whole problem by using [non-capturing groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) in your regex:

> `(?:x)`
>   Matches *x* but does not remember the match. These are called non-capturing parentheses. The matched substring can not be recalled from the resulting array's elements `[1]`, ..., `[n]` or from the predefined `RegExp` object's properties `$1`, ..., `$9`.

If I'm reading your code right, you'd want:

```
/^(?:([a-z]+)|([0-9]+)) (week|day|year)(?:s)? (before|after) (.*)$/
```

You could also replace `(?:s)?` with `s?` since there's no need to group a single literal like that:

```
/^(?:([a-z]+)|([0-9]+)) (week|day|year)s? (before|after) (.*)$/
```

In either case, that you leave you with:

```
[__, text, number, period, relation, timestamp] = match
```

You could use an [array slice](http://coffeescript.org/#slices) to get rid of the leading `__`:

```
[text, number, period, relation, timestamp] = match[1..]
```

The `match[1..]` is a hidden call to [`Array.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) since the destructuring isn't smart enough (yet) to just skip `match[0]` when breaking `match` up. That extra method call may or may not matter to you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have wildcard assignments like that. You could use a double underscore __, like this

```
[first, __, third] = [1, 2, 3]
```

Personally, I would name the second variable in a way that makes sense, even if it is not used afterwards.

Comment: Heh, that's _exactly_ what I ended up doing; using double underscore, I mean.